# Responsive image size both image (pixel) size and file (byte) size just like in Google plus

Tags: image-processing, web-applications, responsive-design, thumbnails

The link below is an example image link I got from google plus. If you change the width value of the URL, the image size change as well and it has a smaller file size. For example, change the width from **1017** to **100**

[http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Eanf6uMoTPI/VaP0qYA_jUI/AAAAAAAAJcc/dOua5XQcjPE/w**1017**-h678-no/IMG_9439.jpg](http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Eanf6uMoTPI/VaP0qYA_jUI/AAAAAAAAJcc/dOua5XQcjPE/w1017-h678-no/IMG_9439.jpg)

File size: 216.8kB

[http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Eanf6uMoTPI/VaP0qYA_jUI/AAAAAAAAJcc/dOua5XQcjPE/w**100**-h678-no/IMG_9439.jpg](http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Eanf6uMoTPI/VaP0qYA_jUI/AAAAAAAAJcc/dOua5XQcjPE/w100-h678-no/IMG_9439.jpg)

File size: 12.5 kB

Can someone please give an advice on how can I have this feature in my web application, regardless if it uses file system or database. This feature is ideal for displaying thumbnails or resizing images.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this (by the way) was to use SLIR application by Lencioni.  It can crop or resize without altering the original image. It uses a cache to store the resized images to lessen the server load.

https://github.com/lencioni/SLIR